# HTML5 wrap text around image with caption

Tags: html

How do i wrap text around an image with image caption.

i did in the following way, but the caption not coming properly.

```
<html>
<head>
<style>
.textWrap{
            float:left;
            margin:10px;            
        }
        .textWrap p{
            padding-top:3px;
        }
</style>
</head>
<body>
<figure>        
                <img class="textWrap" src="img/index.jpg" />
                <figcaption>Caption goes here</figcaption>
            </figure>   

            <h6>
                Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Sed at ante. Mauris eleifend, quam a vulputate dictum, massa quam dapibus leo, eget vulputate orci purus ut lorem.

            </h6>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 1):

I think you want to float the entire 'figure' element left, not the .textWrap image:

```
figure {
  float: left;
  margin: 10px 10px 10px 0;
}
```

Comment: tanks,its working fine. but how do i apply background for caption

Comment: I'm not sure exactly what you want it to look like: but here's a fiddle showing backgrounds on the entire figure and the caption: http://jsfiddle.net/jhummel/RGe4a/1/

Comment: i want to apply background color only for caption not for entire image. is it possible

Comment: Sure: http://jsfiddle.net/jhummel/RGe4a/2/ Just remove the background from the figure, and put a color on the figcaption element. Be advised, you should put display: block; on both figure and figcaption, as some older browsers like to display them inline.

Answer (score 0):

Try using

```
.textwrap h6 {
 padding-top:3px;
    }
```

as there is no    <p>   tag in your code