# How to wrap text around figcaption

Tags: css, html, css-float

With `float`, I can get the text to wrap around the image in the `figure` tag, but not around the `figcaption` tag, as well. Adding `float` to `figcaption` doesn't do it. Any advice?

Code below is here: https://jsfiddle.net/ujb6bwjq/

```
<html><head><style>
body { width: 200px; }
figure {
       width: 100px;height: 100px;padding: 0px;margin: 10px;
       float:left;
       }
figcaption { font-size: 9pt; }
</style></head>
<body>
       <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Sed at ante. Mauris eleifend, quam a vulputate dictum, massa quam dapibus leo, eget vulputate orci purus ut lorem.</p>
       <figure>        
                <svg width="100px" height="100px"><polygon points="0,0 100,0 100,100 0,0" /></svg>
                <figcaption>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Sed at ante. Mauris eleifend, quam a vulputate dictum, massa quam dapibus leo, eget vulputate orci purus ut lorem.</figcaption>
       </figure>   
       <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Sed at ante. Mauris eleifend, quam a vulputate dictum, massa quam dapibus leo, eget vulputate orci purus ut lorem.</p>
</body></html>
```

Related but not helpful to me: [HTML5 wrap text around image with caption](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20367160/html5-wrap-text-around-image-with-caption)

Comment: Do you mean like this? https://jsfiddle.net/ujb6bwjq/1/ Or you want the figcaption to appear side by side with the svg element?

Comment: No, that's not it.  I'd like the figcaption to the left under the image, with text wrapping around both.  Maybe you're seeing something different, but I see that the text wraps around the svg but collides with the figcaption, even though both svg and figcaption are in the same <figure> tag with float:left

Comment: ...
OH, I'm wrong.  display:table plus float:left did it.  I'd tried display, but only block and inline, not table.  that did it. Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Took me a while to understand what you meant, but the simplest solution is what Mr Lister said: remove the `height` property from your `figure` CSS selector:

```css
body {
    width: 200px;
}
figure {
    width: 100px;
    padding: 0px;
    margin: 10px;
    float: left;
}
figcaption {
    font-size: 9pt;
}
```

```html
<body>
    <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Sed at ante. Mauris eleifend, quam a vulputate dictum, massa quam dapibus leo, eget vulputate orci purus ut lorem.</p>
    <figure>
        <svg width="100px" height="100px">
            <polygon points="0,0 100,0 100,100 0,0" />
        </svg>
        <figcaption>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Sed at ante. Mauris eleifend, quam a vulputate dictum, massa quam dapibus leo, eget vulputate orci purus ut lorem.</figcaption>
    </figure>
    <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Sed at ante. Mauris eleifend, quam a vulputate dictum, massa quam dapibus leo, eget vulputate orci purus ut lorem.</p>
</body>
```

If you have to keep the explicit `height: 100px;` in there, then adding `display: table;` will give you the same result.

Comment: Ehm, yes, I meant property rather than attribute. Sorry for the confusion.

Comment: @MrLister No worries; I knew what you meant! It was the question's description that was a little confusing.